# Struts programs showing Error 404

Tags: struts2

I am working on my project and not able to load the index.html (the very first file of my project). 
Now web.xml is checked first for which file to load and that I checked many times so still why am I not able to get the very first page ?? [image]

```
  //web.xml
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
<display-name>Assignment5</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>

<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
```

// For some Reason my struts.xml was not uploading as code so I am uploading // that as picture

[image]

Comment: Clients cannot hit files under WEB-INF directly. I can't tell where your `index.html` is, but it it's there, it's invisible to the browser.

Comment: hey @DaveNewton thanks for quick response the index.html is in the web-inf folder as shown in the structure image

Comment: Ok, well, that won't work.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry not web-inf it is under web content as shown in the structure,

Answer (score 0):

You put index.html parallel to WEB-INF

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of your solution. If your suggestion answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.